# A question about how to express a fraction as ${1\over q_1}+{1\over q_2}+ \cdots+{1\over q_N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, elementary-number-theory, induction, fractions

Let $x$ be a positive rational number, strictly between $0$ and $1$. Prove that there is a finite strictly increasing list of positive integers $2 \leq q_1<q_2<\cdots<q_N $ such that $$x={1\over q_1}+{1\over q_2}+ \cdots+{1\over q_N}.$$

I have tried many methods, such as mathematical induction. I know it is obvious that $\frac{1}{m}$ is right for assumption, but when I begin to prove $\frac{2}{m}$, I feel it is hard to find some patterns for $\frac{2}{m}$. Thus, maybe my thoughts are wrong.

Also, I still tried to change the fraction so that the numerator will be smaller and smaller. But I still cannot find a way to lower the numerator. Can someone help me solve the question? Or, can someone give me some hints. I will appreciate you very much!

Comment: yes x is a positive rational

Comment: To see other ways to do this, look at Egyptian fractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $q=m/n$ rational, with $q\in (0,1)$, and hence
$$
\frac{1}{k}\le\frac{m}{n}<\frac{1}{k-1}
$$
for some integer $k>1$. If $\frac{1}{k}=\frac{m}{n}$, we have nothing to prove. Otherwise,
we have
$$
\frac{m}{n}-\frac{1}{k}=\frac{km-n}{kn}=\frac{m'}{n'}>0.
$$
But $\dfrac{1}{k-1}>\dfrac{m}{n}$ implies that $n>m(k-1)$, or $m>km-n=m'>0$.

Hence, after we subtracted the the nearest and smallest fraction of the form $1/k$, the remainder $m'/n'$ has smaller numerator.

Hence, in at most $m$ steps this procedure ends, and thus we obtain the sought for representation.

Comment: Oh, that's great